# SSH changing port issue

Tags: ssh, debian

I'm running Debian 10. I've read like 10 instructions on how to change default SSH port from 22 to any desired but none of it seem to work.

I changed `#Port 22` to `Port 1111` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Restarted the service with `service ssh restart` and even rebooted the server.

And then I tried to connect: `ssh -p 1111 user@hostname` to no avail. It looks like the port is not open but I have no firewall whatsoever.

Seconly I tried to connect the usual way: `ssh user@hostname` which gives me `ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Connection refused`.

`service ssh status` gives me

```
Nov 04 05:32:04 localhost systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Nov 04 05:32:04 localhost sshd[904]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 1111.
Nov 04 05:32:04 localhost sshd[904]: Server listening on :: port 1111.
Nov 04 05:32:04 localhost systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.

~# ss -tulpn | grep 1111
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                              0.0.0.0:1111       0.0.0.0:*                                                                                users:(("sshd",pid=904,fd=3))                                                  
tcp   LISTEN 0      128                                 [::]:1111          [::]:*                                                                                users:(("sshd",pid=904,fd=4))
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A firewall is running somewhere.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you connect to port 1111?

Comment: No error message. It just remains blank as if (and it is) trying to connect. Idk if there’s connection timeout, I’m just quitting it using Ctrl+C after some 20 seconds.

Comment: That points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: What’s the best way to determine if I’m running one? As I mentioned (I think) I don’t have one. I also tried to open this port via iptables but it didn’t work either.

Comment: I don’t know much of firewalls but this most common one ‘ufw’ isn’t installed.

Comment: Look for a firewall outside the virtual machine.

Comment: Will do. I’ll try to contact the support then. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For those, who's customer to 1&1 Internet Inc a.k.a. IONOS**

They have their own firewall outside the virtual machine. That was the issue here.

It can be configured under `Network` > `Firewall Policies` in `Cloud Panel`.